# Signature verification in python using compressed public key

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, signature, transaction-verification

I am trying to learn bitcoin blockchain programming. I am trying to verify signature in Transaction with txid: 4269fdc239d027922dcec96f1ae283dbaff10e2d1bd49605661d091e79714956

I am getting BadSignatureError

Raw Transaction

```
./bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 4269fdc239d027922dcec96f1ae283dbaff10e2d1bd49605661d091e79714956
01000000017f950ab790838e0c05e79856d25d586823fe139e1807405a3f207ff33f9b7663010000006b483045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990012102b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90ffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac00000000
```

Decode Raw Transaction

```
./core/bitcoin-0.16.0/bin/bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 01000000017f950ab790838e0c05e79856d25d586823fe139e1807405a3f207ff33f9b7663010000006b483045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990012102b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90ffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac00000000
{
  "txid": "4269fdc239d027922dcec96f1ae283dbaff10e2d1bd49605661d091e79714956",
  "hash": "4269fdc239d027922dcec96f1ae283dbaff10e2d1bd49605661d091e79714956",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 224,
  "vsize": 224,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "63769b3ff37f203f5a4007189e13fe2368585dd25698e7050c8e8390b70a957f",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990[ALL] 02b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90",
        "hex": "483045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990012102b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.03993627,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 69f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd87",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "3BMEXVvXXRFh2eJ9Eji115xfqJjWmLTCf8"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 4.83049847,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac6 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1LWPbaYN2jqhv9oZvYHxYKXuaiR1qJn52i"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here "asm" contains Signation and Public Key

```
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "63769b3ff37f203f5a4007189e13fe2368585dd25698e7050c8e8390b70a957f",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990[ALL] 02b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90",
        "hex": "483045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990012102b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
```

To obtain Signature

```
3045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990
=>
0x30 DER
0x45 Length
0x02 Type Integer
0x21 Length of R
0x00d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2 (R)
0x02 Type Integer
0x20 Length of S
0x78787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990 (S)

Removing 00 from R
Signature = R + S = d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f278787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990
```

Compressed Public Key 
02b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90

Uncompressing Public Key
Code

```
def getFullPubKeyFromCompressed(x_str: str):
        prefix = x_str[0:2]
        print("prefix = %s" % (prefix))
        x_str = x_str[2:]
        x = int(x_str, 16)
        print("x = %x" % (x))
        p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
        y_squared = (x**3 + 7) % p
        y = modular_sqrt(y_squared, p)
        y_str = "%x" % y
        print("y_str = %s" % (y_str))
        y_is_even = (int(y_str[-1], 16) % 2 == 0)
        if prefix == "02" and y_is_even == False or prefix == "03" and y_is_even == True:
                y = p - y
                y_str = "%x" % y
        print("y = %s" % (y_str))
        return "04" + x_str + y_str

prefix = pubkey[0:2]
if prefix == "02" or prefix == "03":
        pubkey = getFullPubKeyFromCompressed(pubkey)[2:]
elif prefix == "04":
                pubkey = pubkey[2:]
print("full public key = %s" % pubkey)
```

Output:

```
x = b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90
y_str = cacc567dc3036f2fceb1b6f16676285b153821eb79825dae124b17b9e29479cb
y = 3533a9823cfc90d0314e490e9989d7a4eac7de14867da251edb4e8451d6b8264
full public key = b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d903533a9823cfc90d0314e490e9989d7a4eac7de14867da251edb4e8451d6b8264
```

Transaction single time SHA256 hashing as this will be done again signature verification
Code

```
hashval = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(raw_txn)).digest())
txn_sha256 = bytes.decode(hashval)
print("txn_sha256 = %s" % (txn_sha256))
```

Output

```
txn_sha256 = fb0c792bfba8139654cffd2818bdd56f3541d11fb43ea46f646c3477de3d2e40
```

We have all three information to verify signature now

```
txn_sha256 = fb0c792bfba8139654cffd2818bdd56f3541d11fb43ea46f646c3477de3d2e40
pubkey = b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d903533a9823cfc90d0314e490e9989d7a4eac7de14867da251edb4e8451d6b8264
sig = d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f278787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990
```

I execute check signature program

```
sig_b = bytes.fromhex(sig)
txn_sha256_b = bytes.fromhex(txn_sha256)
vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(pubkey),curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
if vk.verify(sig_b, txn_sha256_b, hashlib.sha256) == True: # True
        print("Signature is Valid")
else:
        print("Signature is not Valid")
```

But I get BadSignatureError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitcoin_localapis.py", line 294, in <module>
    sigcheck(sig, pubkey, raw_txn)
  File "bitcoin_localapis.py", line 202, in sigcheck
    if vk.verify(sig_b, txn_sha256_b, hashlib.sha256) == True: # True
  File "/home/vizeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ecdsa/keys.py", line 101, in verify
    return self.verify_digest(signature, digest, sigdecode)
  File "/home/vizeet/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ecdsa/keys.py", line 113, in verify_digest
    raise BadSignatureError
ecdsa.keys.BadSignatureError
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the Raw Transaction I used for signature verification.

Original Raw Transaction

```
./bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 4269fdc239d027922dcec96f1ae283dbaff10e2d1bd49605661d091e79714956
01000000017f950ab790838e0c05e79856d25d586823fe139e1807405a3f207ff33f9b7663010000006b483045022100d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f2022078787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990012102b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90ffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac00000000
```

Parsing this manually

```
01 00 00 00 Version 
01 Input Count 
7f 95 0a b7 90 83 8e 0c 05 e7 98 56 d2 5d 58 68 23 fe 13 9e 18 07 40 5a 3f 20 7f f3 3f 9b 76 63 (32 Bytes of Previous Transaction ID)
01 00 00 00 Output Index (vout index) 
6b Script Length (107 bytes) (Replace this)
48 30 45 02 21 00 d8 62 94 03 cd 3b 49 95 0d a9 29 36 53 c6 27 91 49 c0 29 e6 b7 b1 53 71 34 2d 0d 2c e2 86 c8 f2 02 20 78 78 79 85 a6 44 e9 4f d9 24 6f 6c 25 73 33 36 c9 4a f5 f0 0d 9d 34 a0 7d c2 f9 e0 98 7e f9 90 01 21 02 b7 26 d7 ea e1 1a 6d 5c f3 b2 36 2e 77 3e 11 6a 61 40 34 7d ce e1 b2 94 3f 4a 28 97 35 1e 5d 90 Script (and Replace this)
ffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac00000000 Remaing bytes 
01 00 00 00 Append SIGHASH_ALL
```

Replace Portion of transaction marked above with scriptPubKey. There seems to be no reason why we do this. Refer this discussion:

> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=102487.msg1123257#msg1123257

compressed pubkey = `02b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d90`

Address from Public Key:
Code

```
def sha256d(bstr):
    return hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(bstr).digest()).digest()

def convertPKHToAddress(prefix, addr):
    data = prefix + addr
    return base58.b58encode(data + sha256d(data)[:4])

def pubkeyToAddress(pubkey_hex):
        pubkey = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_hex)
        round1 = hashlib.sha256(pubkey).digest()
        h = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
        h.update(round1)
        pubkey_hash = h.digest()
        return convertPKHToAddress(b'\x00', pubkey_hash)
```

Output Address

```
1LWPbaYN2jqhv9oZvYHxYKXuaiR1qJn52i
```

Hash160 of Address (from https://blockchain.info/address/1LWPbaYN2jqhv9oZvYHxYKXuaiR1qJn52i)

```
d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6
```

Adding size to hashed address

```
14 d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6
```

Input Transaction Hash = `63769b3ff37f203f5a4007189e13fe2368585dd25698e7050c8e8390b70a957f`

This transaction has following out scriptPubKey. One of them is spent in this transaction which we will find out.

```
out index 0: 76 a9 14 89 df 43 9f 5e 48 c0 e7 ec d6 91 af fa 1f b8 39 15 7e 0a 71 88 ac
out index 1: 76 a9 14 d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6 88 ac
```

Decoding scriptPubKey

```
OP_DUP = 0x76 (first byte of both)
OP_HASH160 = 0xa9 (second byte of both)
OP_EQUALVERIFY = 0x88 (second last byte of both)
OP_CHECKSIG = 0xac (last byte of both)
```

So we need Hash160 of public key in scriptSig of transaction we are investigating. This we have already calculated. Adding script to hash160 from public key we get

```
76 a9 14 d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6 88 ac
```

Size of New script = 25 = 0x19

New script

```
19 76 a9 14 d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6 88 ac
```

So we found that this is equal to scriptPubKey of second out of input transaction. This out is marked spent.

Now after inserting this script to Raw Transaction.
We get new Raw Transaction

```
01 00 00 00 Version 
01 Input Count 
7f 95 0a b7 90 83 8e 0c 05 e7 98 56 d2 5d 58 68 23 fe 13 9e 18 07 40 5a 3f 20 7f f3 3f 9b 76 63 (32 Bytes of Previous Transaction ID)
01 00 00 00 Output Index (vout index)
19 76 a9 14 d5 f9 50 ab e0 b5 59 b2 b7 a7 ab 3d 18 a5 07 ea 1c 3e 4a c6 88 ac (New Script)
ffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac00000000 (Remaining)
01 00 00 00 Append SIGHASH_ALL
```

Which becomes New Raw Transaction

```
01000000017f950ab790838e0c05e79856d25d586823fe139e1807405a3f207ff33f9b7663010000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688acffffffff021bf03c000000000017a91469f3757380a56820abc7052867216599e575cddd8777c1ca1c000000001976a914d5f950abe0b559b2b7a7ab3d18a507ea1c3e4ac688ac0000000001000000
```

We need to just apply SHA256 once as signature verify method also applies SHA256. 
Code

```
hashval = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(raw_txn)).digest())
txn_sha256 = bytes.decode(hashval)
print("txn_sha256 = %s" % (txn_sha256))
```

Output :

```
txn_sha256 = 3d3b8997cc9c0e2275bd0f694b862f7d0bee4f7aee2456891e038322884070ad
```

Now we have all three variables required for signature verification

```
pubkey = b726d7eae11a6d5cf3b2362e773e116a6140347dcee1b2943f4a2897351e5d903533a9823cfc90d0314e490e9989d7a4eac7de14867da251edb4e8451d6b8264
sig = d8629403cd3b49950da9293653c6279149c029e6b7b15371342d0d2ce286c8f278787985a644e94fd9246f6c25733336c94af5f00d9d34a07dc2f9e0987ef990
txn_sha256 = 3d3b8997cc9c0e2275bd0f694b862f7d0bee4f7aee2456891e038322884070ad
```

Now execiting Signature Verification code
code

```
sig_b = bytes.fromhex(sig)
txn_sha256_b = bytes.fromhex(txn_sha256)
vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(pubkey),curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
if vk.verify(sig_b, txn_sha256_b, hashlib.sha256) == True: # True
        print("Signature is Valid")
else:
        print("Signature is not Valid")
```

Gives Signature is Valid